# How to composite an image into a gif using Imagick?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick

Basicly I'm trying to merge a static image into a gif with Imagick. I think I'm close to it, but the resulting gif so far implements a black image into the gif instead of the image I expect. The dimensions are correct though. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['url'])){
    $gif = new Imagick('original.gif');
    $img = new Imagick($_POST['url']);

    $file_dst = 'result.gif';

    $gif = $gif->coalesceImages();

    foreach($gif as $frame){
        $frame->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
        $frame->setImageArtifact('compose:args', "1,0,-0.5,0.5");
        $frame->compositeImage($img, Imagick::COMPOSITE_MATHEMATICS, 0, 0);         
    }

    $gif = $gif->deconstructImages();
    $gif->writeImages($file_dst, true);

    echo "done";
}

?>
```

Am I missing something that's causing this issue? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Here is some examples I hope you help full click this link. http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.coalesceimages.php

Comment: @Kheteshkumawat I've already found the problem. Instead of `COMPOSITE_MATHEMATICS` I had to use `COMPOSITE_DEFAULT`. That fixed the issue. Just hoping someone can answer the question as to WHY that fixed it.